# PHP Define security issues?

Tags: php

**index.php:**

```
define("included", true);
```

**INCLUDED PAGES:**

```
if (included !== true) header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

The purpose for the codes was to disallow access directly but allow it if included. I am not sure if this opens any risks. I am not allowed to override `.htaccess` so I am stuck with a PHP alternative.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems fine. The only suggestion is add an `exit;` statement inside the if, as a header will not kill the application and it will still process. That and constants are generally ALL CAPS, that would be my other suggestion :)

Comment: It's usually indicative of a bad application design. Code executing in main should be avoided. Includes should define functions, so such workarounds are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *sexier* way is...

```
defined('included') OR exit;
```

That is, use the correct function ([`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)) to see if a value is defined, and then exploit [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Also, you can probably just use an existing define rather than create one specifically, e.g. your bootstrap file may define something like...

```
define('DOCROOT', realpath(basename(__FILE__)));
```

...in which case you would be safe to use `DOCROOT`.

You should also be keeping any PHP files besides your bootstrap above your document root, and then ensuring your site is safe from [directory traversal attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, but I would change it to:

```
if (!defined('included')) { 
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); 
    // actually make the request stop, since clients will not stop on 404 headers
    die(); 
}
```

cheers

Comment: just a header on it's own will continue the rest of the page. {header(....);  exit;}

Comment: @Alister, yes, I already added that :)
@tjmoore you mean including your files from within another file on another place in the server? It depends on your server's security configurations.

Answer (score 1):

How about just moving all the files that aren't supposed to be accessed directly to a directory outside of webserver's document root?

Answer (score 0):

*Usually* you use a setup like you are doing, but perform a `die` or `exit` to abort it, and not worry about redirecting. Even if they know the file exists, it's useless if you can't access the contents.

**common.php** (or your index.php, depending your setup)

```
<?php
  define('IN_PAGE',true);
  ...
?>
```

**include_file.php**

```
<?php
  defined('IN_PAGE') or die('Unallowed access'); // or header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); exit;
  ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is:

```
<?php
   @runtime_presence();
```

Which leads to a **fatal** error if the function stub wasn't centrally defined before. (Header redirecting and a pretty error message are not useful as security measure.)